# Is there an equivalent django-admin like feature for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, django-admin

I'm looking for anything that allows similar editing of tables and doesn't have a software cost associated to it.

Answer (score 1):

Not in bare ASP.NET. The Django framework can get away with having an admin interface like this because its ORM, template engine, and MVT mechanisms are all fixed. Some ASP.NET frameworks may have it, but there will be a software cost regardless.

Comment: I guess at this point I'd be happy to pay. Can you recommend some commercial examples of how to achieve a similar automatic admin like interface over a set of SQL tables?

Comment: I have not a clue. I have never dealt with ASP.NET in any capacity. I just happen to know Django.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Dynamic Data Site in Visual Studio 2010, which does the same thing like Django-admin site. It requires Entity Framework.